# business card. Indesign

Tags: business

I'm not a designer but am trying to find out how to centre my name on a business card in Indesign?
I've created a text box but the type isn't completely centred within the box and I don't know how to do that either.
Is there a simple way that Indesign will centre only the text, and ignore the text box?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solutions are:

A. Make the text box the width of the space you want the text to be centered in. So in your case this would mean make the box the width of the business card.

B. Alternatively you can right click your text and do uh... Fit Frame to Content (going from memory so might not be exact wording)